# Find files using wildcard in directory using Linux

Tags: linux, bash, find

So I have a directory that has a number of files. I'm wondering what I need to find files within that directory.  My files have a naming convention and then a last name.  I'd like to find by the naming convention.

```
/MyDir/MySubDir/2016_01_randomLastNameABC

/MyDir/MySubDir/2016_01_randomLastNameDEF

/MyDir/MySubDir/2016_01_randomLastNameGHD

/MyDir/MySubDir/2016_01_randomLastNameDGD

find "/MyDir/MySubDir/2016_01_*"
```

I keep getting an error that says:

> "linux file names usually don't contain slashes"

It must not like the fact that I'm trying to search a directory

Comment: Since you already know the path then just use `ls` instead of `find`, perhaps ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the files afterwards? Depending on that, you can use a fileglob directly, no `find` required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try
`find ./MyDir/MySubdir/ -name "2016_01_*"`

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
find /MyDir/MySubDir/ -name "2016_01_*"
```

test,

```
~$ find ./market/public/static/ -name *.js
./market/public/static/view3dview.js
./market/public/static/ng-file-upload.min.js
./market/public/static/codemirror-min.js
./market/public/static/model_upload_app.js
```

Comment: Not enclosing `2016_01_*` in quotes can cause issues if there are any matching files in the parent directory.

Comment: @codeforester I check it now, thank you for your comment.

Comment: @codeforester I've checked it. The matching files in the parent directory is not listed. I use ubuntu14.04LTS,

Comment: When I said parent directory, I meant the current directory of the shell that invokes `find`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed it, I check it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /MyDir/MySubDir -name "2016_01_*"
```